# cpp linker failed, can't trace source of error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am relative new to cpp and I have stumbled upon a linker failure I can't trace.

I was trying out [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest), and I tried to rewrite the inline header sample ([sample-3inl.h](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/samples/sample3-inl.h)) to a separate source and header file.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
Project structure:
├── src
│   ├── queue.cpp
│   ├── queue.h
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
├── test
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── gtest
│   │   │   ├── googletest   
│   ├── unit_test
│   │   ├── unit_test.cpp
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
```

[Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) works fine, I have tried it with the original [sample-3inl.h](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/samples/sample3-inl.h).

Linker failiure error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Queue<int>::Enqueue(int const&)", referenced from:
      QueueTest::SetUp() in dummy.cpp.o
  "Queue<int>::Queue()", referenced from:
      QueueTest::QueueTest() in dummy.cpp.o
  "Queue<int>::~Queue()", referenced from:
      QueueTest::QueueTest() in dummy.cpp.o
      QueueTest::~QueueTest() in dummy.cpp.o
  "Queue<int>::Size() const", referenced from:
      QueueTest_IsEmptyInitially_Test::TestBody() in dummy.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

source code (myqueue.cpp, myqueue.h, and unit_test.cpp) can be found on the following [page](https://github.com/BARJ/cpp-linker-failure-) for simplicity.

Tried to find what causes the error for a couple of hours now but I can't find it, really want to know what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was trying out Google Test, and I tried to rewrite the inline header sample (sample-3inl.h) to a separate source and header file.

You can't do that with a template. For more information, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)